# $(this) inside $('#something').css({...})

Tags: jquery, this

I tried to apply css with jquery to a div element, but it wont accept the $(this) parameter. I wonder why cant I use $(this) as a referer to the div element.

```
blabla.css({
'top': $(window).width()/2-$(this).width()/2+'px', 
'left': $(window).width()/2-$(this).width()/2+'px'  
});
```

ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'width'

Thanks in advance..

ps: I know I can use here a direct id call inside the `$()`, but I expected `this` will work.

Comment: Please provide the context of this piece of code (where it is called and how, in turn, you call *that* function). Only then we can know what `this` refers to and give a proper solution. Or do you simply expect `this` to refer to `blabla`? What is `blabla`? (I think @Matt was on the right track (you should undelete your anser ;)))

Comment: my guess is that you are inside something like an anonymous function or something and `this` refers to it, not to your element.

Comment: assume that: blabla = $('#somediv')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `$(this)` is `blabla`, why not use  `blabla.width()` instead `$(this).width()`?

Comment: because blabla is now something like: FW.model.box.div. And Its just too long

Comment: just store it in a local variable, like `var bla = $('FW>model>box>div')`

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are not running a callback, you're passing an object to `.css`. So, `this` doesn't not refer to `blabla` - the element - but to the current context defined when the function that contains this code was called (and that could vary). This context doesn't have `.width`, and then you get an error.

You will have to explicitly reference the width, as in `blabla.width()`

Answer (score 1):

You probably try

```
$("#blabla").css('top',function(){
   alert($(this).width());
 });​
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution for this also.  I wanted to use jQuery to center floating divs.  I created this function that is called onload and on window resize:

```
$("div[class~='floatCenter']").each(function () {
    var elementWidth = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().outerWidth() / 2;
    var marginPixels = parentWidth - elementWidth;
    $(this).css("margin-left", marginPixels + "px");
});
```

I ended up going another route in centering my div using CSS, but the concept of using the `$(this)` remains the same.